# Фиксация блока без сдвигания контента

Tags: jquery, css

Есть див, которому присваивается `.fixed` при скроле. Вроде, все просто, но, при фиксации, остальной контент, сдвигается вверх, занимая освободившееся место, и страница "прыгает". Как избавиться от этого? У дива непостоянная ширина, так что обернуть не получится. Смотреть можно [здесь](http://gprealty.ru/category/aprtmnts/), пациент - `#uwpqsf_id`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил сам, следующим образом:
После блока, которому суждено зафиксироваться, добавляем `<div class="spacer"></div>` и стилизуем примерно так:

```
block.fixed ~ .spacer {
height: 'высота блока, когда он не был фиксирован';
}
```

Прыжка контента больше не происходит, с добавлением анимации выглядит шикарно.

Answer (score 0):

Сдвиг происходит потому что блок с `position:fixed` вырывается из потока страницы и привязывается к координатам окна. Как решение я бы вам посоветовал в тот момент, когда происходит присваивание класса .fixed, добавить margin-top у контента равный высоте хедера (или вернее того, чему класс присваивается)

Comment: класс присваивается форме поиска, на мобильных устройствах она перестраивается в 2 ряда, то есть, задать статичный margin не получится. Видимо, придется не фиксировать ее на маленьких экранах, а на больших поступить так, как вы посоветовали.

Comment: высоту можно [посчитать](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect) в момент присвоения.